# Angular JS, accordion and html content

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an accordion in my Ionic/Angular JS app wherein the hidden items are blocks of html-formatted text. I've found Angular JS code to build the accordion, but the examples have all used numeric values to populate the accordion's content.  When I add html tags plus text to the test content, I get a string, rather than expressed html.  I've tried sanitizing the string (although not sure if I have the context right), but that doesn't change its appearance.

My relevant js (I've left off the reveal/hide code for the accordion) is:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic','ngSanitize'])
myapp.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.groups = [{title: 'Background'}];
  $scope.items = [{bkgtxt:  $sce.trustAsHtml('<p><strong>Do not guess</strong></p>')}];
});
```

My HTML (for just a single accordion item) is:

```
<ion-list ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <ion-item class="item-stable"
           ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
           ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
           <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
           &nbsp; {{group.title}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-accordion"
           ng-repeat="item in items"
           ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
           {{item.bkgtxt}}
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously a newbie here, so any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks, Tom

Comment: you can't use expressions (`{{ }}`) to bind arbitrary HTML content.  Unless there is a specific need to store HTML in your variables (user created content) you should just stick to keeping the HTML in your template and out of your variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ng-bind-html` directive to bind `html` to element, there is no need on sanitization of html content as you already did it.

**Markup**

```
<ion-list ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <ion-item class="item-stable"
           ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
           ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
           <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
           &nbsp;<span ng-bind-html="group.title"><span>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-accordion"
           ng-repeat="item in items"
           ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" 
           ng-bind-html="item.bkgtxt">
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```